# jQuery .load() messes up my <a> tags

Tags: jquery, css

Okay, here is the deal. I have a site where I am loading all the contents dynamically. I am basically loading the content from other pages into a div on the main page. If i strip it away all the functions and bells and whistles I have narrowed it down to it being the .load() function. Whenever it performs it my links go haywire, out of place and I cannot find it. I tried searching but nobody seems to have the problem I have but if I missed anything I apologise. It has been frustrating me and I just want to know what it is.

The Javascript

```
function openContent(x)
{
        var q= x+".php #info";
    $("#content").load(q,function() { $('#content').mCustomScrollbar({ scrollButtons:{ enable:false} }); });
    $("#container").animate({opacity:1.0,width:'890px'},3000);
    $('#content').animate({opacity:1.0,width:'890px'},3000);
    $('.close').animate({opacity:1.0,},12000);
}
```

The PHP

```
<div id="background">
    <div id="logo"></div>
        <input type="button" class="web-development" onclick="openContent('development')"/>
        <input type="button" class="graphic-design" onclick="openContent('graphic-design')" />
        <input type="button" class="photography" onclick="openContent('photography')" />
        <input type="button" class="projects" onclick="openContent('projects')" />
        <input type="button" class="contact" onclick="openContent('contact')" />
        <input type="button" class="close" onclick="closeContent()" />
    <div id="container" ><div id="content"></div></div>
    <div id="footer">Copyright <?php echo date('Y'); ?> &copy;</div>
</div>
```

When the buttons are clicked they load the appropriate content into the content div.

The CSS

```
#background
{
    background: url('../Images/background.png') no-repeat;
    margin-right:auto;
    margin-left:auto;
    height:800px;
    width:1280px;
}

#logo
{
    background: url('../Images/logo.png') no-repeat;
    width: 235px;
    height: 175px;
    z-index: 999;
    position:absolute;
    top: 10px;
    left: 535px;
}

/*container to affect the scroll */
#container
{
    background: url('../Images/content_bg.png');
    height:650px;
    width:1px;
    opacity:0.0;
    padding: 90px 40px 0px 40px;
    position:absolute;
    z-index:7;
    left:165px;
    top:70px;
}
/* deocarting content */
#content
{
    background: url('../Images/content_bg.png');
    opacity: 0.0;
    width:1px;
    height:650px;
    padding: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
    z-index:8;
    color:#f4cf00;
    /* for IE 5&6&7 opacity hack */
    filter: alpha(opacity=0);
    font-family:"Gabriola";
    font-size:20px;
    overflow:auto;

}

/* classes for the buttons on the main page */
.projects
{
    position:absolute;
    top:160px;
    left:425px;
    background: url('../Images/projects.png') no-repeat;
    width:130px ;
    height:640px;
    z-index: 2 ;
    border: 0px solid;
}
```

And that's the CSS dictating how the content div and containers are defined. Like I said It works if I dont use the load function and just have the content fade in manually. Use the load and my links disappear and I have to use tab to locate them

Comment: inspect them in browser console and see what css may be causing issues. Sounds like you could have some invalid html...make sure page and load content pass w3c validation. Don't intiate all plugins until isolate issue

Comment: Thanks! Turns out when I was loading the other pages. There was one anchor tag that was not closed that caused everything to go haywire. I normally use firebug and it was not showing up as any kind of error. The validation did the trick. Thanks once again

Answer (score 0):

It might be worth replicating your problem and seeing what the response values say? If you can catch the error in future and tell the user, that would be nice.

```
$("#content").load(
    q,
    function(responseContent, responseStatus, responseObject) {
        console.log(responseContent);
        console.log(responseStatus);
        console.log(responseObject);
    }
);
```

Hope that helps.